# Problema C++ resultado de codigo

Tags: c++

Mi problema es el siguiente, desconozco por que el resultado que me lanza el siguiente código, si hice algo mal o pudiese mejorar en algo, agradecería muchísimo la ayuda, gracias!.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void datos();
void cambiarSigno(int vect[], int longitud);
void mostrarVector(int vect[], int longitud);

int vect[100], longitud;

int main()
{
    datos();

    cambiarSigno(vect,longitud);

    mostrarVector(vect,longitud);

    return 0;
}

void datos()
{
    cout << "Ingrese longitud del vector: " << endl;
    cin >> longitud;

    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese valor: " << endl;
        cin >> vect[i];

    }
}

void cambiarSigno(int vect[],int longitud)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese valor: " << endl;
        vect[i] = (-1 * vect[i]);
    }
}

void mostrarVector(int vect[],int longitud)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        cout << vect[i] << " ";
        
    }
}
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

```
Ingrese longitud del vector:
4
Ingrese valor:
1
Ingrese valor:
2
Ingrese valor:
3
Ingrese valor:
4
Ingrese valor:
Ingrese valor:
Ingrese valor:
Ingrese valor:
-1 -2 -3 -4
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Programacion c++\Cambiar signo vector\Debug\Cambiar signo vector.exe (proceso 3184) se cerró con el código 0.
Presione cualquier tecla para cerrar esta ventana. . .
```

Entonces allí no entiendo por que se me repite reiteradas veces el *ingrese valor*.

Comment: Porque así lo has escrito en el código. Tienes la siguiente línea en cada vuelta del bucle en el que cambias de signo a los enteros: `cout << "Ingrese valor: " << endl;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los últimos cuatro `"Ingrese valor: "` se imprimen en la función de `cambiarSigno`:

```
void cambiarSigno(int vect[],int longitud)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese valor: " << endl;
        vect[i] = (-1 * vect[i]);
    }
}
```

Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
void cambiarSigno(int vect[],int longitud)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        vect[i] = (-1 * vect[i]);
    }
}
```

### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Evita usar formaciones estáticas, usa contenedores.
- Evita el uso de variables globales.
- Pasa tus colecciones de datos por referencia para ahorrarte copias.
- Usa los bucles de rango, son menos propensos a errores.

Con estos consejos, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

using enteros = vector<int>;

enteros datos()
{
    cout << "Ingrese longitud del vector: " << endl;
    int longitud;
    cin >> longitud;

    enteros resultado(longitud, 0);

    for (auto &valor : resultado)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese valor: ";
        cin >> valor;
    }

    return resultado;
}

void cambiarSigno(enteros &valores)
{
    for (auto &valor : valores)
    {
        valor = -valor;
    }   
}

void mostrarVector(enteros &valores)
{
    for (auto &valor : valores)
    {
        cout << valor << " ";
    }   
}


int main()
{
    auto vect = datos();

    cambiarSigno(vect);

    mostrarVector(vect);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVHLasMwEDx7v2JJoTiQQNrmFDu@91zoXZVUI5CloIcvpd/urmTLSWhP9U0z49nZWX657Llmpp@mB2W4jkJiq6wPTrKhgys2Sh6s6wCiV6ZHwwbpL4xL9EE0BZUmSGc9nnGWt8qEjtiCCxasr7fwBRW3MWDb4ubV9E56idqaXoUoUEi9/H7CTZJII3QDFXmtInpyZbDrbhCoyhjyizowYevC7vCwTYpP67BmMVh8HJmmx@kq3kJFuX4Hy0KK0iRyHpohen@TpZMhOnO1aYDQ0SqBnA0firk31Rtbl2zzXOlzCX/EWekcZkbPuF8nVqv9kK7E3Huu6p/@ZdmZTVvnPecpkBofmDL5Ykhftkq3oUjLLanVxNztmhSFuE95yyzFHaiwaTrCEzzDCxzhBw)</kbd>.

Comment: ahhhh alli vi, que crack, gracias man!